# Is there any documentation explaining the meaning of each variable at the output of adb shell settings list?

Tags: android, adb

The question describes itself.
I need to know if there is a documentation explaining each variable of the output of the following:

```
adb shell settings list global
adb shell settings list secure
adb shell settings list system
```

I failed to find it on the internet.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global

Comment: I checked out these links and there are a lot of missing variables. I'm using a Samsung Note 9.